# Finding length of string in Scala

Tags: scala, string-length

I am a newbie to scala
I have a list of strings -
`List[String] (“alpha”, “gamma”, “omega”, “zeta”, “beta”)`

I want to count all the strings with length = 4

i.e I want to get output = 2.

Comment: You can simply use `l.count(_.length == 4)` to get your result, here `l` is your `List[String]`

Answer (score 7):

You can do like this:

```
val data = List("alpha", "gamma", "omega", "zeta", "beta")

data.filter(x => x.length == 4).size

res8: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `count` function as

```
val list =  List[String] ("alpha", "gamma", "omega", "zeta", "beta")

println(list.count(x => x.length == 4))
//2 is printed
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks @volia17 :)